# How to change CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to change the a raster's CRS, because i want to fit it with the others layer and rasters.

When i load it, appears a text "The CRS hasn't been defined: will be used as CRS EPSG 4326: WGS 84".
So the raster appears shifted respect to the others.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with SR?

Comment: Reference System sorry

Comment: I think you should edit your question to say that because my guess was Spatial Reference.

Comment: add some information of your raster layer. `gdalinfo` output if you can do that, or Layer extent from Layer properties -> Metadata

Answer (score 2):

Your Raster seems to have no SRS assigned. So first of all you have to find out the native SRS of your raster. That can be tricky and difficult. See Layer Properties -> Metadata and search for Layer Extent. From that on you need to find matching Projections for your region. After that, it's basically trial and error.

When you know the correct SRS, you can set it on loading into QGIS. If you want to make the change permanent, you can use the tool Raster -> Projections -> Assign Projection. Choose your file and the correct SRS and press OK.

When you next load the raster into QGIS, it should be in the correct position.